# Mootools compatability syntax from 1.12 to 1.4.5

Tags: javascript, jquery, mootools

Currently I am forced to upgrade to `Mootools 1.4.5` from my old version `1.12`, but I have code here that is no longer working due to the upgrade.  It might be due to deprecated syntax.  Does this need to be re-written?

Please help.

```
jQuery.noConflict();
    window.addEvent('domready', function() {

        SqueezeBox.initialize({});

        $$('a.modal').each(function(el) {
            el.addEvent('click', function(e) {
                new Event(e).stop();
                SqueezeBox.fromElement(el);
            });
        });
    });


        window.addEvent('domready', function() {
            myFx = new Fx.Slide($E('.option'), {duration: 300}).hide();
            $E('.option').setStyle('display', 'block');
            $$('.switcher').addEvent('click', function() {myFx.toggle();});
            $$('.switcher').addEvent('mouseleave', function() {myFx.slideOut();});
        });
```

Comment: Looks good, you can change `new Event(e).stop();` to just `e.stop().` Change also `$E` to `document.getElement`.

Comment: Did you try my suggestions? did you get it working?